# Meaning of :: in onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter} in React

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I am new to event handling in React. In the below snippet, what does the :: mean in onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter} ?

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

mouseEnter() {
    console.log('mouse enter')
    this.setState({opacity: 0.5})
}

mouseLeave() {
    console.log('mouse leave')
    this.setState({opacity: 1})
}

render() {
     <div style={{opacity: this.state.opacity}}>
         <img src={src} onMouseEnter={::this.mouseEnter} onMouseLeave={::this.mouseLeave} />
     </div>
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::` is from ES7. It is equivalent to `onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter.bind(this)}`

Comment: Actually, it is a Stage 0 proposal, so it never landed in JavaScript (we are at ES11 or so right now).
https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/stage-0-proposals.md

OP must use some form of transpilation in their project to make it work.